# Prevent a pseudo element from changing the width/scroll width of a parent container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a green area, a pseudo element, to the right of of a blue element, the pseudo element's parent, such that the green element doesn't increase the width of the red scroll area, the container. My actual use-case is a bit more complex, but it relies on using a pseudo element so this below example sets up the problem well. I've included two blue areas and two green areas simply to show that I want the scroll area to scroll if the blue width is large enough. I just don't want the green area to be part of the calculation:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}

span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="width:50px"></span>
  <span style="width:250px"></span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogr9qu8g/3/)

Ideally the green pseudo element would be pulled out of the layout completely and have no width. The problem is for the background-color to work it requires a width. I'm strongly suspecting I can't use background-color for this. If something like outline-right: 500px solid green; existed that would be a solution, but I can't find anything like that. I can't use box-shadow, border-right, or anything else since those all add to the width. Is there any mechanism in CSS that would allow the green area to not be included in the red's scroll width area?

Comment: I'm confused...if you don't want the green in the "scroll width", why have it all? BTW, what's a "scroll width?"

Comment: Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ogr9qu8g/4/ I applied the pseudo-element on parent div instead. I'm not sure what you want so I didn't post this as answer. If it satisfy as per your requirement, tell me so I'll post it as answer :P

Comment: @zer00ne It's a visual aesthetic in my UI for a selection element. Scroll width refers to the size of the scroll area that determines how far a user can scroll horizontal and vertical. The idea in my problem is to make the green area not count toward that scroll area.

Comment: @Cons7an7ine I had two spans in my example specifically to show that such a solution would not work for me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ogr9qu8g/6/ This seems to work for me. Might update with an answer unless I create something better. My coworker was toying around with various ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an outer container with the inner one set to overflow: hidden; removes the absolutely positioned elements from being included in the width and scroll area calculation.

Using min-width: 100%; ensures that the inner container takes up at least the whole width of the outer container.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#first {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
#second {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}
span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
    <span style="width:50px;"></span>
    <span style="width:250px;"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogr9qu8g/7/)